# Running midnight commander in vim occurs visual error

Tags: vim

I tried navigating folders using midnight commander in [vim](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6Fjf.png), so I typed 
`:!mc` to do [running midnight commder in vim](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8rB0X.png) .
And when I type C-o for [returning to vim](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vL6ls.png), terminal screen shows, not the vim screen.

If I edit file from the top `gg i abcdefg`, terminal screen is erased by vim screen like [this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQOZ6.png)

You can see picture of the problem by clicking link.

Comment: What about using `F10` to return to vim from Midnight Commander?

Comment: @MichalPrzybylowicz solved problem. I realized running mc in vim makes no benefits. moving directory in mc doesn't effect vim.